# Show spinner below title in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How do I show the spinner below title in android actionbar? Is this possible, as of now I am getting the spinner just beside the title?

Like this:

[image]

I would like the get the spinner below "Above SPINNER" Title?

Here is what I have done till now:

```
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("ABOVE SPINNER");
    
    items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actions);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener=new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) 
        {           
            Log.e("NavigationItemSelected", items[itemPosition]); // Debug
            return false;
        }
    };

    getActivity().getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
```

How to get the spinner below Title?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used to customize Toolbar in the following way:

Create seperate layout named toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#005387"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/ToolBarStyle.Event"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#005387"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And include this in your main.xml file

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

To use Toolbar add following:

```
     final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                if (toolbar != null)
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Toolbar");

                toolbar.setSubtitle("Sub Title");

                // to set home button you can use

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Add this in your Styles.xml under your base theme.

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

**NOTE:** Create separate style if you want toolbar in particular activity and add that style in your manifest.xml.

Use spinner in normal way you used to do.
In your Main activity class use spinner in same traditional way and
also in this manner any custom toolbar can be made :)

Comment: Thank for the quick reply. Can't this be done using actionbar?  Spinner has Item 1 and subItem 1 - Is it possible to show subItem1 as the drop down items and Item 1 has the title?

Comment: This can't be done using ActionBar, ActionBar are old use Toolbar instead. Yes everything is possible. Create a custom Adapter by extending BaseAdapter for spinner.

Comment: @TheDevMan if you found my answer correct please mark it as tick.  It will really help me :).  Also if you need further help, please tell me.

Comment: But I have already implemented actionbar to my app. I would have to change everything then. Is it possible to just have toolbar for a particular screen?

Comment: yes it is possible and you don't have to change much I guess.  It requires only few lines of code.  Do you want me to tell how to add toolbar?

Comment: It would be great if you could tell me that too? Also will it work on API 14 too? I am supporting my app from API 14. (ICS)?

Comment: Toolbar support library supports min API 7.

Comment: @TheDevMan, Check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74307/discussion-between-ajeet-and-thedevman).

Comment: You can add vertical offset for spinner